# How do you install the linux-lowlatency kernel and why does it stops at version 5.15?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, latency

I have been reading today about `linux-lowlatency` and I am more and more confused. First of all, is the install as simple as `sudo apt install linux-lowlatency` and then reboot? Do I need to select a different boot option in the Grub menu? I gave it a quick shot and `uname -r` still returned 6.2 which seems to be the generic version?

Secondly, I'm using POP_OS 22.04 LTS, basically Ubuntu, and the kernel is in version 6.2. Yet, `linux-lowlatency` seems to be stuck at 5.15 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-lowlatency). What is the reason behind this version lag and can it be an issue?

Comment: If `POP!_OS` has upgraded to the `6.x Kernel`, then you'll need them to provide the `low latency Kernel` for you.  As for Ubuntu 22.04, the proper package to match current Kernel version is: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/linux-lowlatency-hwe-22.04-edge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu servers usually keep the kernel version to a stable, LTS kernel, so perhaps Pop OS or you installed 6.2 manually. The version lag shouldn't be an issue - in fact, it may prevent some issues associated with newer kernel versions.

You can install a mainline kernel, but you'd probably have to find it online or build it from source, as the Mainline ppa doesn't support it anymore

As for how to install it, after you run `sudo apt install linux-lowlatency`, you will need to update GRUB: `sudo update-grub`, and maybe change the boot order with `grub-customizer` if necessary.

The Ubuntu low latency kernel is usually not intended for desktop use, and is for embedded applications with high latency requirements though. You shouldn't expect big gains from performance or the like.

Comment: The kernel is updated with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, with default repositories. I I understand correctly, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is using the 5.19 kernel while POP_OS 22.04 LTS already upgraded to the 6.2 version.
One more question, what is "mainline"? What does it mean?

And for the GRUB part, the low-latency kernel should show up as a separate boot entry in the GRUB menu? Correct?

For context, the intended use is a desktop stimulation PC used in a research context where ms accuracy is expected.

Comment: Perhaps I used the term "mainline" slightly incorrectly, but I was referring to the most recent kernel - I got the term from a tool used to install these updated kernels, but I don't think it supports low-latency kernels. I think you understood correctly. And yes, for the GRUB part, there should be a separate boot entry after you update GRUB, but it may be the default or hidden under a submenu.

Comment: "The Ubuntu low latency kernel is usually not intended for desktop use,..." -- Does not match my anecdotal experience. Low latency kernels work _great_ for my desktop use and dramatically decreases perceived UI latency, audio skips, etc. when heavily loading my systems. I would agree if you said "real time kernel", but what can I say... Try the low latency kernel and see how it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

While bobtho's  answer above is correct, it needs to be modified if you are using the [Hardware Enablement (HWE)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) kernel series. Then you need to do:

```
sudo apt install linux-lowlatency-hwe-22.04
```

where 22.04 should be replaced with your ubuntu version.

To answer the original question about getting the low-latency kernel 6.2 in ubuntu 22.04, using the HWE version will get you a 6.2 kernel.